# Get request's first response status code

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, request, http-status-code-301

I am requesting example.com  than it redirects me to www.example.com  with 301 or 302 status and then I get response from  www.example.com  with code 200. I want to get all statuses not only the last. I use 'request' module in my node server.
Here is my code

```
 app.post("/check", function(req, res) {
  var link = req.body.url;

  var opts = {
    uri: link,
    gzip: true,
    followRedirect :function (resp) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  request(opts, function (error, res, body) {
    if (res.statusCode > 300 && res.statusCode < 400 && res.headers.location) {
      if (url.parse(res.headers.location).hostname) {
      } else {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want the output to be but try this:

```
app.post("/check", function(req, res) {
  var link = req.body.url;
  var redirectCodes = [];

  var opts = {
    uri: link,
    gzip: true,
    followRedirect :function (resp) {
      redirectCodes.push(resp.statusCode);
      return true;
    }
  };
  request(opts, function (error, res, body) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      body: body,
      redirectCodes: redirectCodes
    }, null, 2));
  }
});
```